# What is the equivalent of .WillCascadeOnDelete(false) in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

What is the equivalent of .WillCascadeOnDelete(false) in EF Core?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTransactionHistoryClassImport>()
                .HasMany(e => e.ProductTransactionHistoryClassDetailImports)
                .WithOne(e => e.ProductTransactionHistoryClassImport)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Details Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencecollectionbuilder.ondelete?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_ReferenceCollectionBuilder_OnDelete_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DeleteBehavior_)

The OnDelete method takes a DeleteBehavior enum as a parameter:

`Cascade` - dependents should be deleted

`Restrict` - dependents are unaffected

`SetNull` - the foreign key values in dependent rows should update to NULL

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTransactionHistoryClassImport>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ProductTransactionHistoryClassDetailImports)
            .WithOne(e => e.ProductTransactionHistoryClassImport)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

Comment: From the description of DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction 
>  Note: it is unusual to use this value. Consider using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull`
 instead to match the behavior of EF6 with cascading deletes disabled.

Answer (score 2):

The code is inside of the OnModelCreating method (ModelBuilder modelBuilder) inside of your DbContext Class and can be used as follows:

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

OR

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

OR

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
```